# Stripping all qualifiers from a function type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, c++17

Given a possibly varargs function type with possibly a *cv-qualifier-seq* and possibly a *ref-qualifier*, is it possible to write a type trait that strips all the qualifiers without writing 4 * 3 * 2 = 24 partial specializations?

```
template<class T>
struct strip_function_qualifiers;

template<class R, class... Args>
struct strip_function_qualifiers<R(Args...)> { using type = R(Args...); };

template<class R, class... Args>
struct strip_function_qualifiers<R(Args..., ...)> { using type = R(Args..., ...); };

template<class R, class... Args>
struct strip_function_qualifiers<R(Args...) const> { using type = R(Args...); };

template<class R, class... Args>
struct strip_function_qualifiers<R(Args..., ...) const > { using type = R(Args..., ...); };

template<class R, class... Args>
struct strip_function_qualifiers<R(Args...) const &> { using type = R(Args...); };

template<class R, class... Args>
struct strip_function_qualifiers<R(Args..., ...) const & > { using type = R(Args..., ...); };

// etc. etc. for each possible combination (24 in total)
```

And with [the new transactional memory TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4301.pdf) adding `transaction_safe` to the mix, does that mean we'll need to write 48 partial specializations for this?

---

**Edit**: Quoting the description of these weird function types ([dcl.fct]/p6, quoting N4140):

> A function type with a *cv-qualifier-seq* or a *ref-qualifier*
>   (including a type named by typedef-name (7.1.3, 14.1)) shall appear
>   only as:
>
> - the function type for a non-static member function,
> - the function type to which a pointer to member refers,
> - the top-level function type of a function typedef declaration or *alias-declaration*,
> - the *type-id* in the default argument of a type-parameter (14.1), or
> - the *type-id* of a *template-argument* for a *type-parameter* (14.3.1).
>
> [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> typedef int FIC(int) const;
> FIC f; // ill-formed: does not declare a member function
> struct S {
>    FIC f; // OK
> };
> FIC S::*pm = &S::f; // OK
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]
>
> The effect of a *cv-qualifier-seq* in a function
>   declarator is not the same as adding cv-qualification on top of the
>   function type. In the latter case, the *cv-qualifiers* are ignored.
>   [*Note*: a function type that has a *cv-qualifier-seq* is not a
>   cv-qualified type; there are no cv-qualified function types. — *end
>   note* ] [ *Example*:
>
> ```
>  typedef void F();
>  struct S {
>     const F f; // OK: equivalent to: void f();
>  };
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]
>
> **The return type, the *parameter-type-list*, the
>   *ref-qualifier*, and the *cv-qualifier-seq*, but not the default arguments (8.3.6) or the exception specification (15.4), are part of
>   the function type.** [*Note*: Function types are checked during the
>   assignments and initializations of pointers to functions, references
>   to functions, and pointers to member functions. — *end note* ]

Comment: What exactly is a `const` function? Or a `volatile` function?

Comment: @MSalters That are cv-qualifiers that can be added to a declaration of a member function.

Comment: @Columbo: Member functions aren't free functions. And the code above only works for free functions. It's missing the class type. This is no coincidence, the cv-qualification of a member function is effectively a cv qualification of the class type. Just consider the type of `this` inside cv-qualified member functions.

Comment: @MSalters So then is [this possible implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) full of completely unnecessary specializations?

Comment: I admit that's a bit confusing. But the same site is very explicit: ["For any type T (including incomplete types), other than **function type** or reference type, there are three more distinct types in the C++ type system: const-qualified T, volatile-qualified T, and const-volatile-qualified T"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)

Comment: @MSalters I edited the question to use the more precise term. See [dcl.fct]/6. It's easy to strip way the `T::*` part of a pointer-to-member-function, leaving a function type that can have a cv-qualifier-seq and/or a ref-qualifier.

Comment: I believe this can be solved with macros with in some way.. Try to construct a macro above a macro like: `#define A(x) ... x ...` `#define B(x) A(x) A(x const)` `#define C(x) B(x) B(x &)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see no way around this - define it once and reuse it whenever possible.
Such a huge amount of specializations is avoidable when the qualifiers are **top-level** - we could use `std::remove_cv` or `std::remove_reference` in that case, removing all orthogonal qualifiers in each step. Unfortunately this is not applicable for functions as explained in the paragraph quoted by you: The e.g. cv-qualifier is part of the function type, and not top-level. `void() const` is a fundamentally different type than `void()`, and thus the both have to be matched by two different partial specializations.

You can shorten all specializations using macros though:

```
#define REM_CTOR(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define SPEC(var, cv, ref) \
template <typename R, typename... Args> \
struct strip_function_qualifiers<R(Args... REM_CTOR var) cv ref > \
{using type = R(Args... REM_CTOR var);};

#define REF(var, cv) SPEC(var, cv,) SPEC(var, cv, &) SPEC(var, cv, &&)

#define CV(var) REF(var,) REF(var, const) \
                REF(var, volatile) REF(var, const volatile)

template <typename> struct strip_function_qualifiers;

CV(()) CV((,...))
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/267eb53939b5b7f5).
Boost.PP is possible as well:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/enum.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/elem.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_product.hpp>

#define REF  (&&)(&)()
#define CV   (const volatile)(const)(volatile)()
#define VAR  (())((,...)) // Had to add a comma here and use rem_ctor below,
                          // otherwise Clang complains about ambiguous ellipses

#define SPEC(r, product) \
template <typename R, typename... Args> \
struct strip_function_qualifiers<R(Args... BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM( \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, product))) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, product)   \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(2, product)>  \
{using type = R(Args... BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, product)));};

template <typename> struct strip_function_qualifiers;

BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT(SPEC, (VAR)(CV)(REF))
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32a381d0ed0f839e). Both methods won't get much longer when adding new qualifiers such as `transaction_safe` or `transaction_safe_noinherit`.

---

Here is a modified `SPEC` that also defines certain trait members.

```
#include <type_traits>

#include <boost/preprocessor/tuple/size.hpp>

// […]

#define SPEC(r, product)                                         \
template <typename R, typename... Args>                          \
struct strip_function_qualifiers<R(Args... BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM(  \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, product))) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, product)   \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(2, product)>  \
{                                     \
    using type = R(Args... BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ENUM(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, product))); \
                                                            \
private:                                                    \
    using cv_type = int BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(1, product);      \
    using ref_type = int BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(2, product);     \
public:                                                     \
    using is_const    = std::is_const<cv_type>;             \
    using is_volatile = std::is_volatile<cv_type>;          \
    using is_ref_qualified = std::is_reference<ref_type>;               \
    using is_lvalue_ref_qualified = std::is_lvalue_reference<ref_type>; \
    using is_rvalue_ref_qualified = std::is_rvalue_reference<ref_type>; \
    using is_variadic = std::integral_constant<bool,                          \
                       !!BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, product))>; \
};
```

Comment: Is there a particular version of boost you need for this to compile? I get a lot of `error: macro "BOOST_PP_TUPLE_REM_CTOR" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given`

Comment: Same error, now just with `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_REM_1` instead.

Comment: @Barry Weird. What is your Boost version, and what compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc 4.7.2 and boost 1.46. Although with boost 1.55, I instead get `template argument 1 is invalid` 16 times on the `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT` line.

Comment: @Barry I don't think 4.7 supports ref-qualifiers.

Comment: In that case just remove the ref-qualifier bit.

Comment: @T.C. Ah, yeah, that'll do it. So yeah, boost 1.55 works (even without the "1, ") and boost 1.46 doesn't (even with it). Thanks. Anyway, this is very cool.

Comment: @T.C. You are correct. I didn't find it at first as they called it "Rvalue references for `this`" in [the support listing](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html).

Comment: I suppose I should be thankful that I can't really think of a use case for manipulating these qualifiers beyond "remove them all and give me a sane function type" and "does this function type have this qualifier", which means that two full sets of partial specializations should be enough...

Comment: @T.C. Do you want me to implement the latter and add it to the answer?

Comment: @Columbo Nah, not necessary unless you want to :) I have in my mind a master template with 24 partial specializations that maps the qualifiers into a bitmask and then it's trivial to write `has_const_qualifier` etc. using that.

Comment: @T.C. Added the code I thought of. I'm thinking of a sexy method of detecting variadic functions.

Comment: @T.C. Found one: `!!BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE(BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM(0, product))`. TIL that `2` cannot be converted to `bool` as a template-argument.