# Finding out the return type of a function, lambda or function

Tags: c++, c++11

This seems to be solved for the case of lambdas in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943525/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-the-parameter-type-and-return-type-of-a-lambda). But that one is a 2011 answer and I'm looking for a general case: lambdas, regular functions, and functors. And, if possible, by means of the most modern c++ language additions. (Note: `g++ -std=c++1y test.cpp`).

So, given a function (or a lambda), I'm trying to find out what its return type is. For instance, to declare a variable (simplified case).

```
using namespace std;

template<typename F>
void test (F h) {
  // any of the following should be equivalent to int a; int b; int c;
  decltype(h) a; // <<<<< wrong
  result_of(h) b; // <<<<<< wrong
  result_of<decltype(h)> c; // <<<<<< wrong
}

int a_function (int i)  { 
  return 2*i; 
}

int main ()  {
  test (a_function);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: When you have two overloaded h functions: `int h (int)` and `float h(float)`, what do you expect `result_of(h)` to return?

Comment: @Zadirion Good point. But in my problem, either there will be only one h() or, actually, h() will be an input parameter for another function.

Comment: Why do you want to find the return value of a function **without knowing how you are going to call it**?  How is that useful?  Or do you know how you are going to call it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that:

1. You want only the return type.
2. You don't know what are/will be the types of arguments (so neither `decltype()` nor `std::result_of<>` is an option.
3. The functor object passed as argument will not have an overloaded or generic `operator()`.

then you can use the below trait that infers the return type of any functor object:

```
template <typename F>
struct return_type_impl;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(Args...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(Args..., ...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(*)(Args...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(*)(Args..., ...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(&)(Args...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(&)(Args..., ...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args..., ...)> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args...) &> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) &> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args...) &&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) &&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args...) const> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args...) const&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args...) const&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) volatile> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) volatile&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args...) volatile&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) volatile&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args...) const volatile&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct return_type_impl<R(C::*)(Args..., ...) const volatile&&> { using type = R; };

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct return_type
    : return_type_impl<T> {};

template <typename T>
struct return_type<T, decltype(void(&T::operator()))>
    : return_type_impl<decltype(&T::operator())> {};

template <typename T>
using return_type_t = typename return_type<T>::type;
```

*Tests:*

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename F>
void test(F h)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<return_type_t<F>, int>{}, "!");

    return_type_t<F> i = 1;
}

int function(int i) { return 2*i; }

int c_varargs_function(...) { return 1; }

struct A
{
    int mem_function(double, float) { return 1; } 
};

int main()
{
    // Function
    test(function);

    // C-style variadic function
    test(c_varargs_function);

    // Non-generic lambda
    test([](int i) { return 2*i; });

    // Member function
    test(&A::mem_function);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45dce91f54dd3c86)

Comment: Is there no way to avoid your traits (or compactify it using some `std` functionality)?

Comment: @Walter. There should be. As the traits are no more that boilerplate code, it should exist simply `return_type<F>` the same way it exists `decltype(a)`.

Comment: @Walter because its functionality is limited (as I listed at the beginning), I doubt such trait will be introduced to the Standard Library (currently there is no equivalent, you need to know the arguments' types that you will use, and utilize `decltype(func(1,2,3))` or `std::result_of_t<F(int,int,int)>`. Also [there is no easy way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27743745/3953764) to compactify it without a help of macro definitions

Comment: @Walter On top of the limited functionality, its use cases are very narrow.  I hesitate to say "useless", but it is pretty close to useless.  Overloads should be expected in C++: you should know how you are going to use a type before you ask it what it will return.

Comment: I still find it amazing how much people love answers like this about C++, and how much people love the language features that make these kinds of atrocities possible.

Answer (score 7):

`std::result_of<h(int)>::type a;`

(Taken from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).)