# How does `std::is_const` work on non-static member method types?

Tags: c++

**Question:**

How does `std::is_const` work on non-static member method types? Is a `const` member method not a const-qualified type?

**Example:**

```
class D {};
```

We will have

```
std::is_const_v<void (D::*)() const> == false
```

**Follow-up:**

Can the constness of a member non-static method be determined (at compile/run time)?

Comment: Possibly helpful [Stripping all qualifiers from a function type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743745/stripping-all-qualifiers-from-a-function-type)

Comment: The standard library doesn't have traits for this. The traits are notoriously tedious to implement. It would probably best to use something like [boost::callable_traits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/callable_traits/doc/html/index.html) which does it for you.

Comment: Reference to boost::callable_traits proves very pertinent as a place to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, functions are not first-class citizens: you can't have objects with function type (you can have function objects, but that's a different concept).

`void (D::*)() const` is a pointer type. `std::is_const` will tell you whether the pointer is const or not, so:

- `std::is_const_v<void (D::*)() const> == false`;
- `std::is_const_v<void (D::* const)()> == true`.

There is no standard trait to check whether a member function has a const qualifier. However, you can make your own. François Andrieux's answer would be the traditional way of doing that, but as mentioned in the comments, you need 48 specializations to make it complete.

Here is another, perhaps more concise way:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct ArbitraryType {
    template <typename T>
    operator T & ();
    template <typename T>
    operator T && ();
};

template<bool, bool, class T, class Arg, class... Args>
struct is_invocable_with_const_first_arg_impl : std::bool_constant<
    is_invocable_with_const_first_arg_impl<
        std::is_invocable_v<T, Arg const&, Args...> || std::is_invocable_v<T, Arg const&&, Args...>,
        std::is_invocable_v<T, Arg&, Args...> || std::is_invocable_v<T, Arg&&, Args...>,
        T, Arg, Args..., ArbitraryType
    >::value
> {};

template<bool b, class T, class Arg, class... Args>
struct is_invocable_with_const_first_arg_impl<true, b, T, Arg, Args...> : std::true_type {};

template<class T, class Arg, class... Args>
struct is_invocable_with_const_first_arg_impl<false, true, T, Arg, Args...> : std::false_type {};

template<class T, class Arg>
struct is_invocable_with_const_first_arg : is_invocable_with_const_first_arg_impl<false, false, T, Arg> {};

template<class T, class Arg>
inline constexpr bool is_invocable_with_const_first_arg_v = is_invocable_with_const_first_arg<T, Arg>::value;

template<class T>
struct is_const_member_func_ptr;

template<class R, class C>
struct is_const_member_func_ptr<R C::*> : std::bool_constant<
    is_invocable_with_const_first_arg_v<R C::*, C>
    || is_invocable_with_const_first_arg_v<R C::*, C>
> {};

template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is_const_member_func_ptr_v = is_const_member_func_ptr<T>::value;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cc6Tnxadx)

Comment: I got a lot of value from this answer as well. However, just like with Francois' answer, it's not obvious to me how I could extend this to handle overloaded PMFs (without a `static_cast` in the client code, which would defeat the purpose).

Comment: @RayaneCTX I'm not sure I get what you mean. If you have a pointer `R (S::* ptr)(Args...) const`, then `is_const_member_func_ptr_v<decltype(ptr)> == true`. Remove the `const`, and you get `false`. I don't see how overloads come into play. If `f` is overloaded, you can't do `decltype(&f)`.

Comment: I realized I am asking something completely different. I'm essentially asking about what I should do if I can't use `decltype` because the PMF is overloaded; i.e., what should I do if I can't obtain a well-defined `T` input parameter. Accepting this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a standard trait to check for this type of constness. But it is a relatively straight forward one to write :

```
#include <type_traits>

// Base template
template<class T>
struct is_const_member_func_ptr;

// Specialize for pointers to non-const member function
template<class T, class C, class ... A>
struct is_const_member_func_ptr<T (C::*)(A...)> : std::false_type {};

// Specialize for pointers to const member function
template<class T, class C, class ... A>
struct is_const_member_func_ptr<T (C::*)(A...) const> : std::true_type {};

// Convenient constant template
template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is_const_member_func_ptr_v = is_const_member_func_ptr<T>::value;
```

Usage :

```
class D {};

static_assert(is_const_member_func_ptr_v<void (D::*)() const> == true);
static_assert(is_const_member_func_ptr_v<void (D::*)()>       == false);
```

Live example : https://godbolt.org/z/Y9EjY5jzf

---

Edit : Example using an actual defined member function

```
// Usage
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

class D 
{
public:
    void foo() {}
    void foo_c() const {}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_const_member_func_ptr_v<decltype(&D::foo)> << '\n';
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_const_member_func_ptr_v<decltype(&D::foo_c)> << '\n';
}
```

Live : https://godbolt.org/z/9fvYs834W

Comment: Don't forget to write the remaining 47 specializations for all combinations of `&`, `&&`, `const`, `volatile`, `noexcept`, and `...`. D:

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's a good point. Though you don't need to write all combinations, you just need to process the argument given through an additional trait to strip the particular modifiers. Edit : Nevermind, it's a bit trickier than I thought...

Comment: The only trick that comes to mind is shaving half of specializations (either all const or non-const ones) by only checking `is_member_function_pointer_v`.

Comment: Can you show an example using `is_const_member_func_ptr` on an actual declared member function? That would be the "follow-up" from the question, although I bet that's the actual question, because I don't see how a trait that tells you if `const` is in the type you just wrote would be of any use.

Comment: @Nelfeal Traits are often used when the type is not specifically spelled out, usually as a template parameter or deduced. Updated the answer.